# Add external C++ libraries to react native Turbo app

Tags: react-native, react-native-turbomodule

I am trying out the new react-native Turbo feature.
The calls to the cpp code works as the documentation mentions.

Is there a way to add external C++ libraries like [cryptopp](https://www.cryptopp.com/).
I have my github repo here [RNTurbo](https://github.com/Wahid-Abdul/RNTurbo).

Comment: Hi, did you get a solution for this? I have been trying to link oneTBB for multi-threading facilities without success. `react-native-builder-bob` docs mention C++ at exactly one place and no more.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it took me quite some time to get a working cmake configuration.

If you follow the instructions [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/the-new-architecture/cxx-cxxturbomodules) you should end up with the following file structure:

```bash
CxxTurboModulesGuide
├── android
│   └── app
│       ├── src
│       │   └── main
│       │       └── jni
│       │           ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       │           └── OnLoad.cpp
│       └── build.gradle (updated)
├── ios
│   └── CxxTurboModulesGuide
│       └── AppDelegate.mm (updated)
├── js
│   └── App.tsx|jsx (updated)
└── tm
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── NativeSampleModule.h
    ├── NativeSampleModule.cpp
    ├── NativeSampleModule.ts|js
    └── TurboModules.podspec
```

At this point everything should build and work as expected.

And now you can add a library, for example [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-170) very simple one.

In the `tm` directory you create a new folder with the name of the library  or you could just clone the desired library into the `tm` folder.

For the simplicity's sake we use the `MathLibrary` sample from Microsoft.

Now we and up with the following file structure:

```bash
CxxTurboModulesGuide
├── android
│   └── app
│       ├── src
│       │   └── main
│       │       └── jni
│       │           ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       │           └── OnLoad.cpp
│       └── build.gradle (updated)
├── ios
│   └── CxxTurboModulesGuide
│       └── AppDelegate.mm (updated)
├── js
│   └── App.tsx|jsx (updated)
└── tm
    ├── MathLibrary
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── MathLibrary.cpp
    │   └── MathLibrary.h
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── NativeSampleModule.h
    ├── NativeSampleModule.cpp
    ├── NativeSampleModule.ts|js
    └── TurboModules.podspec
```

The `tm/MathLibrary/CMakeLists.txt` file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(MathLibrary VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(MathLibrary MathLibrary.cpp)
```

And the main `tm/CMakeLists.txt` file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)

add_compile_options(
        -fexceptions
        -frtti
        -std=c++17
)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/MathLibrary) # <=== add new
add_subdirectory(MathLibrary) # <=== add new

file(GLOB tm_SRC CONFIGURE_DEPENDS *.cpp)

add_library(tm STATIC ${tm_SRC})

target_include_directories(tm PUBLIC .)
target_include_directories(react_codegen_AppSpecs PUBLIC .)

target_link_libraries(tm
        MathLibrary # <=== add new
        jsi
        react_nativemodule_core
        react_codegen_AppSpecs
)
```

And that's it, now you should have all the necessary files in place to build and use c++ libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your library with https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob - with interactive CLI you can generate a proper project structure with c++ libraries support for both platforms ios and android

[image]